# Is there any way to retreive all youtube videos from playlist using php,javascript

Tags: javascript, php, video, youtube, playlist

Hi friends are there any references where I can get the all video ids from a playlist and display video ids on screen . Am not able to find good reference example

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The only possible is you can get the id of only one video URL at a time. So I think google doesn't offer any API to do so. As far my knowledge there is no possible way to do like what you asked.